# Get Last Page Visited Page Url In JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, back-button

I have three JSPs named **a.jsp** , **b.jsp** and **c.jsp**.

From  **a.jsp** I am going to **b.jsp** .

Then the following code in **b.jsp** `request.getHeader("Referer")` returns **a.jsp**

Again from **b.jsp** I am going to **c.jsp** .

From **c.jsp** I am pressing browser back button to come to **b.jsp**.

Then again the following code in **b.jsp** `request.getHeader("Referer")` returns **a.jsp**

Why is it not returning **c.jsp** ?

Is there any way so that I can get **c.jsp** on the browser back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason could be that your page is cached.

you can check the http header by using firebug.

[image: check out http request header]

**UPDATE 1**

I have created a new project with a.jsp, b.jsp, c.jsp, here is the code:

a.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>a</h1>
        <a href="b.jsp">b</a><br/>
        <a href="c.jsp">c</a><br/>
        <b><%=request.getHeader("Referer")%></b>
    </body>
</html>
```

b.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>b</h1>
        <a href="a.jsp">a</a><br/>
        <a href="c.jsp">c</a><br/>
        <b><%=request.getHeader("Referer")%></b>
    </body>
</html>
```

c.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>c</h1>
        <a href="a.jsp">a</a><br/>
        <a href="b.jsp">b</a><br/>
        <b><%=request.getHeader("Referer")%></b>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works well. you can create a new project with the code, and test it. i am not sure, what is your situation, maybe you are using AJAX, then the referer will only should URL of the last whole page.

Comment: I have checked.The page is not cached.

Comment: @TanmayMandal can you check your http request by using firebug, etc.

Comment: @TanmayMandal were you getting or posting?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">                           I have added this in the source code of b.jsp

Comment: @TanmayMandal and it is working or not? i have tested around by myself, it works all right. it must be something wrong in your code.

Comment: I have tried a lot. It is not working .But always getting the a.jsp as the referrer.

Comment: @TanmayMandal check out UPDATE 1

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get it wrong, when you press the back button on the browser you remove the last page in the stack, meaning that you don't request the page, you just remove the top one. This would mean that you never have a request from c to b.